# Range.copy problem when running excel macro from another application

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I'm trying to run this code in excel from another application.The code runs without problems, however `rngNumber.Copy wsData.Range("A2")` isn't copied. I've tested the same code directly in excel and it was copied perfectly. I think that maybe `rngNumber` isn't set properly when the code is runned from another application. But, I don't get exactly the reason. Any suggestion would be appreciate, thanks.

```
Sub TEST()

' Try to connect to a running instance of Excel.
    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    
    If Err Then
        Err.Clear
        
        ' Couldn't connect so start Excel.  It's started invisibly.
        Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        
        If Err Then
            MsgBox "Cannot access excel."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    ' You can make it visible if you want.  This is especially
    ' helpful when debugging.
    excelApp.Visible = True

    'Open the excel file (through dialog)
    Dim ExcelFilePath As Variant
    ExcelFilePath = excelApp.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")
    If ExcelFilePath <> False Then
        Set wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)
    End If
    
    ' Open the excel file
    Dim wb as Workbook
    Set wb = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    ws.Activate
   
    'Set Worksheet
    Dim wsData As WorkSheet
    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets(2)
    
    'Write column titles
    With wsData
        .Cells(1, "A").Value = "Number"
    End With
           
    'Get column letter for each column whose first row starts with an specific string
     ws.Activate
     Dim sNumber as String
     sNumber= Find_Column("Number") 
        
    'Define variables
    Dim rngNumber As Range
                 
    ' Copy and paste data from "Number" column to Column "A" in Worksheets "Data"
    ws.Activate
    'Find which is the last row with data in "Number" column and set range
    With ws.Columns(sNumber)
        Set rngNumber = Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    'Copy and paste data from "Number" column
    rngNumber.Copy wsData.Range("A2")

End Sub

Private Function Find_Column(Name As String) As String
   
    Dim rngName As Range
    Dim Column As String
    
    With ws.Rows(1)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngName = .Find(Name, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
        ' Calculate Name Column Letter.
        Find_Column = Split(rngName.Address, "$")(1)
                
    End With
    
End Function
```

Comment: @EEM This is the complete question about the issue I asked you.

Comment: Try `Dim rngNumber As excelApp.Range`

Comment: @CDP1802 I tried it but a compile error "user-defined type not defined" appears. Anyway, the posted code is just the first part of a longer code. In the rest of the code I set other ranges and they work perfectly. It's just when the range is defined within the column: ```
 With ws.Columns(sNumber)```

Comment: The issue is `Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))`. This is only selecting 1 Cell, I think you want a range of multiple cells, if so it'd be like `.Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(1,1000))`. You missed the `.` at the start of the range as well.

Comment: There are some problems in your code... 1. Using `On Error Resume Next`, without being followed by `On Error GoTo 0`, in a not working piece of code is a bad idea. It only not let VBA warn, when an error appear (in all the following code). 2 You declared `ws` as `Worksheet` at the `Sub` level and try using it in the `Find_Column` function. VBA does not know what it is and it will warn about it if the completely useless `On Error Resume Next` should not exist. 3. You should use `Option explicit` on top of the module and **declare all used variables**.

Comment: 4. Place `Debug.Print sNumber` after `sNumber= Find_Column("Number")` What does it return in Immediate Window? It probably returns a `nullString`. If not, the way you try setting the range is wrong: `Set rngNumber = Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))`. Your code line tries created a range **in active sheet** (missing a dot: `.Range`) using cells from another sheet. It will work in this way **only if `ws` is the active sheet...

Comment: @FaneDuru @Ryan Wildry  sNumber returns the right column, in this case "G". If I set the range in this way:`Set rngNumber = .Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` then the result is that it copies the data of another column (column "M") from the Worksheets(1) to to Worksheets(2)

Comment: What is the other application Word, Access, PowerPoint ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Autodesk Inventor

Comment: It's not clear to me how your code works in Excel but anyway try declaring `Dim rngNumber as Excel.Range` and add ws to  `Set rngNumber = ws.Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly define the excel object and remove the On Error Resume Next. This works from Word.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

    ' Try to connect to a running instance of Excel.
    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.WorkSheet, wsData As Excel.WorkSheet
    Dim rngNumber As Excel.Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err Then
        Err.Clear
            
        ' Couldn't connect so start Excel.  It's started invisibly.
        Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            
        If Err Then
            MsgBox "Cannot access excel."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' You can make it visible if you want.  This is especially
    ' helpful when debugging.
    excelApp.Visible = True
    excelApp.WindowState = xlMinimized

    'Open the excel file (through dialog)
    Dim ExcelFilePath As Variant
    ExcelFilePath = excelApp.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")
    If ExcelFilePath = False Then
         MsgBox "No file not selected"
         Exit Sub
    End If

    Set wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets(2)
          
    ' Get column letter for each column whose first row
    ' starts with an specific string
    Dim sNumber As String, LastRow As Long
    sNumber = Find_Column(ws, "Number")
    If sNumber = "#N/A" Then
        MsgBox "Column 'Number' not found in " & vbLf & _
                "Wb " & wb.Name & " Sht " & ws.Name, vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
                
    ' Copy and paste data from "Number" column to Column "A" in Worksheets "Data"
    ' Find which is the last row with data in "Number" column and set range
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, sNumber).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngNumber = .Cells(1, sNumber).Resize(LastRow)
    End With
    'Copy and paste data from "Number" column
    rngNumber.Copy wsData.Range("A1")

    excelApp.WindowState = xlMinimized
    MsgBox LastRow & " rows copied from column " & sNumber, vbInformation

End Sub

Private Function Find_Column(ws, Name As String) As String
   
    Dim rngName As Excel.Range
    With ws.Rows(1)
        Set rngName = .Find(Name, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                       LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    End With

    If rngName Is Nothing Then
        Find_Column = "#N/A"
    Else   ' Calculate Name Column Letter.
        Find_Column = Split(rngName.Address, "$")(1)
    End If
    
End Function
```